# Do Universal Spacetimes have Non-perturbative quantum corrections?

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, quantum-gravity, perturbation-theory, non-perturbative

[Universal spacetimes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+spacetime) have the interesting property that their quantum corrections vanish to all loop orders, and can be viewed as classical solutions to speculative theories of quantum gravity like string theory. Does this property persist beyond the perturbative regime, or do we need a more complete theory of quantum gravity to make definitive statements about this class of metrics?

Comment: We sure do need a complete theory of quantum gravity to answer a question about nonperturbative quantum gravity :). I'd add a string-theory tag if I were you, string theorists may know some peculiar localization trick that makes use of supersymmetry to make some general argument about possible nonperturbative behavior.

Comment: @CuriousDroid I think the answer must be that non-perturbative corrections should exist.  Baby universes, wormholes and other $\mathcal{O}(e^{\frac{-1}{g^{\alpha}}})$ effects for $\alpha$ > 1 are expected for quantum gravity on very general grounds.


Does it make sense to talk about a quantum theory of spacetime in which spacetime does not receive quantum corrections nor at any order in perturbation theory nor at the non-perturbative level? That sounds very unlikely in the context of a "quantum theory of spacetime".